# android app crashes when starting/stopping media

Tags: java, android

I am writing a small practice app that plays a sound clip when a button is tapped. In my previous code, this amounts to just the creation of a MediaPlayer object and a call to mp.start() to start the audio.
This works, but now I would like that same button to play only when no sound is playing yet. If sound is playing, stop the audio. A play/stop button.
I tried to do this using the following code:
```

````
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
MediaPlayer mp; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public void goButtonClicked(View v) {
if(mp == null) {
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.wordt);
}
    if(mp.isPlaying()) {
mp.stop();
mp.release();
} 
    else {
mp.start();
    }
}
}
```
````

However now when I run the app, the app crashes when I tap the button. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Logcat please. Thanks!

Comment: Try to add `mp = null` in your stop media player branch. I think that `release()` doesn't null the object, so you will never enter the first if after the first click. Then it should work (cannot test right now).

Comment: @chevalier I tried your suggestion but this didn't fix it, I'm afraid. I don't have a device myself, I have a friend test it. I'm in a bit of a bind since AVD's aren't very accessible and I am fully blind. So I can only write code I think works, deploy the package and pray. Right now it crashes on the first tap and I can't seem to figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your code like this,

```
public void goButtonClicked(View v) {
    if(mp == null) {
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.wordt);
    }
    ....
}
```

What happens here is, `MediaPlayer mp = ...` means you are creating a local variable inside **if** condition. But still your field variable is null. And when the app executes the second **if** condition, it throws a NullPointerException.

Comment: oh wow ...amateur mistake. I redefined mp locally but left the outer mp pointing to null. THanks a lot for the catch :)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize your first mp object, so you see nullPointerException,
and you can delete second mp object